# Need universal/dynamic serialization/marshaling, similar to Terracotta

Tags: java, serialization, jvm, marshalling, terracotta

Problem: The Software I use, Lift, has "user sessions", where one can put any kind of objects, which are preserved between user requests (with a GC timeout). While it's easy to use and powerful, it has one major drawback: the objects aren't serializable, so you cannot distribute them to other server instances to achieve high availability.

Is there an API/tool out there that can take a random object, analyze it's structure through reflection, create a marshaller/unmarshaller that can extract all the object's data, and return it in a format that can then be used to distribute the object to other JVM. The marshaller/unmarshaller itself should be serializable. There should be a way to explicitly define that some data should be ignored, like using transient for example, and it should also be possible to recognize that some referenced objects are actually system objects (singletons) that have to be handled in a special way. Ideally, it should be an iterative process, so you can put a limit to how "big" the object to marshal can be.

This is somewhat similar to what Terracotta does, except that I want to implement my own transport and back-end, and I don't want to use their "enhancer", because it would be very difficult to limit the packages of the classes to modify, and so it would have to modify all my classes at run-time just in case, which would be very expensive.

Edit: Strictly speaking, having my own transport and back-end isn't an absolute must, but Terracotta's server is a Single-Point-Of-Failure, and I want a system that is thoroughly distributed, where I can force a minimum replication level, and where I can forward a request to a server owning a copy of the user session.

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't quite what I wanted, I found out that there is at least one alternative to Terracotta, which is called [XSTM](http://xstm.org/) They seem to have a similar concept, while being more "extensible".